# Yii module inheritance from parent module

Tags: php, yii, yii-components, yii-modules

I have a site in Yii 1 with 3 modules:

- admin
- site1

  - site2

The site2 module is a parent module of site1. And these two modules are pretty similar (there are some controllers that are same).

I want  to reorganize my site to be a parent module (which holds the common views and controllers. the models are the same).

What are the best practices for this?

Answer (score 0):

This can have lot of solution. Here is something from where u can start:

1. U can have some common place where u will keep shared code. We can call that directory 'common' in this case. Than inside this 'common' directory u can organize your shared code based on functionality - behaviors, models, components, actions, widgets, events, and even views (but i not like too much to share views, if u need one view on more places its usually good to make widget for it). U can import this from application config.
2. Its usually much cleaner and more configurable if u break your controllers into action classes and than share that actions between controllers by attach them to controller (good example of this is Catpcha action in default yii application). On this way u can exclude actions in some controllers if u not need them or mix different set of actions if u need that.
3. About shared view files, even u can do it by give full path to view file from any place, I much more prefer to use widgets if there is need to call one view from more controllers. If u call one view on more place from one controller u can use renderPartial() and than include your view into other view, but if u need to call it from more controllers than from organization and functional view its much better to use widget.